# Adding service to Anguar 17 project to start and stop loader - ngx-ui-loader

Tags: angular, angular17, angular-standalone-components, ngx-ui-loader

I am running Angular 17 projects with standalone components.
I want to add a service where i will start and stop the ngx-ui-loader (
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ui-loader).
I can't do normal module where i will provide in root ngxui loader like in older versions, so i am wondering if this can work in Angular17?
When loader is directly called and imported in a standalone component it works.

Current implementation is not working..

Service code:

```
import { Injectable, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxUiLoaderService } from 'ngx-ui-loader';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoaderService {
//   ngxLoader = inject(NgxUiLoaderService);
  ngxLoader = inject(NgxUiLoaderService);

  startLoader() {
    console.error('start');
    console.error(this.ngxLoader);
    this.ngxLoader.start();
  }

  stopLoader() {
    this.ngxLoader.stop();
  }


  loaderConfig =
  {
    "bgsColor": "red",
    "bgsOpacity": 0.5,
    "bgsPosition": "bottom-right",
    "bgsSize": 60,
    "bgsType": "ball-spin-clockwise",
    "blur": 5,
    "delay": 0,
    "fastFadeOut": true,
    "fgsColor": "red",
    "fgsPosition": "center-center",
    "fgsSize": 60,
    "fgsType": "ball-spin-clockwise",
    "gap": 24,
    "logoPosition": "center-center",
    "logoSize": 120,
    "logoUrl": "",
    "masterLoaderId": "master",
    "overlayBorderRadius": "0",
    "overlayColor": "rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.8)",
    "pbColor": "red",
    "pbDirection": "ltr",
    "pbThickness": 3,
    "hasProgressBar": true,
    "text": "",
    "textColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "textPosition": "center-center",
    "maxTime": -1,
    "minTime": 300
  }
}
```

AppComponent.ts

```
`import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { NgxUiLoaderModule, NgxUiLoaderService } from 'ngx-ui-loader';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { StorageService } from './services/storage.service';
import { finalize, first } from 'rxjs';
import { LoaderService } from './services/loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
  imports: [CommonModule, NavbarComponent, NgxUiLoaderModule, LoginComponent],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'CinAppClient';
  userService = inject(UserService);
  storageService = inject(StorageService);
  ngxLoaderService = inject(NgxUiLoaderService);
  loaderService = inject(LoaderService);

  user$ = this.userService.user$;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaderService.startLoader();
    let storageUser = this.storageService.getUser();
    if (storageUser !== null) {
      this.userService.authToken = storageUser.token;
      this.userService
        .refreshToken()
        .pipe(
          first(),
          finalize(() => this.loaderService.stopLoader())
        )
        .subscribe();
    }
  }
}
type here
```

appComponent.html

```
<ngx-ui-loader [bgsType]="'three-strings'" [fgsType]="'three-strings'">
</ngx-ui-loader>`
type here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide the `NgxUiLoaderService` in your app root. In a standalone-based app, it should be done within the `bootstrapApplication` function, located in the `main.ts` file, as following:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [NgxUiLoaderService]
})
```